# How apply css to div in catch statement using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, try-catch

I can apply the background color to the file input box when the user uploads a wrong file type, but can't get it to clear when the user uploads the correct file type afterward. I have the following code working right now:

```
try {
      imgly.run(data);
    } catch (e) {
      if(e.name == "NoSupportError") {
        alert("Your browser does not support canvas.");
      } else if(e.name == "InvalidError") {
        $('#file').css('background-color', 'red');
      }
    }
```

My guess is another `else` statement, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Try taking out the style attribute out of file control. $("#file").removeAttr("Style");

Comment: Have you written any code to 'clear' or change the colour at all or is it just the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red color will be applied on the `catch` statement, in case the `run()` throws an exception.

If the user uploads correctly, it won't fall into the `catch`, so, put the clearance at the end of the try:

```
try {
  imgly.run(data);
  $('#file').removeAttr("style"); // <-- HERE
}
catch (e) {
  if(e.name == "NoSupportError") {
    alert("Your browser does not support canvas.");
  } else if(e.name == "InvalidError") {
    $('#file').css('background-color', 'red');
  }
}
```